# Laravel search for topic by title and generate link

Tags: php, laravel

I'm laravel newbie. I have something like this:
[image: I have smth like this]

Now I wan't to make when click first topic redirect to that topic url. For that I need to use DB:: function. I wan't search by given title, and then get id, etc.. For example i have posts:
[image: posts]

table `name` same as topic title in image above, so I need use DB::select or ::table and search by that name, then print results. How to?

Layout:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Forum</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    @forelse($forums as $forum)
    @forelse($topics as $topic)
    <a href="HERE MUST BE CODE TO POST FOR EXAMPLE http://example.com/topic/pirmas-atnaujinimas/64">{{ $topic->title }}</a><br>
    @empty
    <div class="alert alert-danger">Apgailėstaujame tačiau šis forumas yra tuščias!</div>
    @endforelse
    @empty
       <div class="alert alert-danger">Apgailėstaujame tačiau forumas nerastas</div>
    @endforelse
  </div>
  </div>
  {!! $topics->render() !!}
@stop
```

Thanks in advance ;(

**UPDATED**
viewForum Controller:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use View;

class viewForum extends Controller 
{
    public function showForum($fname, $fid)
    {
        $forums = DB::table('forums')
            ->where('id', $fid)
            ->where('seo_name', $fname)
            ->select()
            ->get();

        $topics = DB::table('topics')
            ->where('forum_id', $fid)
            ->select()
            ->paginate(1);

        return View::make('forum', compact('forums', 'topics'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the relevant controller's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your topic href do this:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/topic/{{ $topic->seo_name }}/{{ $topic->pid }}">{{ $topic->title }}</a><br>
```

In your routes.php add this

```
 Route::get('topic/{fname}/{fid}', 'viewForum@showForum');
```